# dgrijalva/jwt-go can cast claims to MapClaims but not StandardClaims?

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I am creating the token with the following code

```
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.StandardClaims{
    Subject: string(user.Id),
})

tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte("secret"))
```

and trying to parse them with the following code

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
        return nil, UnauthorizedError
    }

    return []byte("secret"), nil
})
if err != nil {
    return -1, UnauthorizedError
}

if !token.Valid {
    return -1, UnauthorizedError
}

claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
if !ok {
    return -1, UnauthorizedError
}

logrus.Info(claims)
```

Why can I not cast my claims to StandardClaims and access claims.Subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can I not cast my claims to `StandardClaims` and access `claims.Subject`?

Conceptually, this is not possible because the `jwt.Parse` function [by default](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#MapClaims) parses claims into an instance of `jwt.MapClaims`. This is a fundamentally different data structure to `jwt.StandardClaims`; there is no way the compiler can automatically convert between the two using a simple type conversion as they represent the data differently.

## Resolution

The library provides the `ParseWithClaims` function, which allows you to specify your own implementer of the `jwt.Claims` interface for claims to be decoded into. You can pass an instance of `jwt.StandardClaims`. For example:

```golang
token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(
    tokenString, &jwt.StandardClaims{},
    func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        // ...
    },
)
```

If possible, the claims will be parsed and decoded into the variable `token.Claims`. The underlying (dynamic<sup>1</sup>) type of the value stored into this variable will be `*jwt.StandardClaims`. This can be used in a type assertion to recover the standard claims from the interface type:

```golang
claims, ok := token.Claims.(*jwt.StandardClaims)
if !ok {
    // handle type assertion failure
}
// do something with "claims"
```

---

Let's dig into the language specification and library definition some more to provide a more rigorous assessment of this claim.

### Background understanding of package types

`jwt.MapClaims` is a defined type with underlying type `map[string]interface{}` ([code](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/map_claims.go#L11)).

`jwt.StandardClaims` is a defined `struct` type ([code](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/claims.go#L15-L26)):

```golang
type StandardClaims struct {
    // Field set elided for brevity, as it is unimportant to the
    // answer.
}
```

Both types implement the `jwt.Claims` interface type ([definition](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/claims.go#L11-L13)), so is assignable to a variable of type `jwt.Claims`:

```golang
type Claims interface {
    Valid() bool
}
```

The `Token` struct has a [field](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/token.go#L27) called `Claims` of type `jwt.Claims` – any value which implements the `Claims` interface can be assigned to `Claims`.

### Type assertion definition

The language spec [specifies](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) for a type assertion expression of the form `x.(T)` to be valid when `T` is not an interface type, the *dynamic type*<sup>1</sup> of `x` must be *identical* to the type `T`. Here, you wish to evaluate the assertion `x.(*jwt.StandardClaims)`; i.e. the asserted type is not an interface type.

The [code](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/parser.go#L19-L21) for `jwt.Parse` eventually calls `jwt.ParseWithClaims` on the default parser, passing in an instance of `jwt.MapClaims` for the claims destination:

```golang
func (p *Parser) Parse(tokenString string, keyFunc Keyfunc) (*Token, error) {
    return p.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, MapClaims{}, keyFunc)
}
```

so the dynamic type of the `Claims` field in your resulting token is of type `jwt.MapClaims`. This type is *different* (i.e. not identical) to the type `jwt.StandardClaims`, because user-defined types are [always different](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) from any other type except themselves. Hence, the type assertion fails.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>**Dynamic types** ([ref](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables)): recall in Go that interface types are fulfilled implicitly by any type which implements a super-set of the methods specified in an interface. If we define an interface of type `MyInterface`, the variable declaration `var x MyInterface` has static type (defined at compile time) `MyInterface`. However, at runtime, we can assign any value which implements `MyInterface` to `x`. The underlying type of the value assigned to `x` at any moment (the type which implements the interface) specifies the *dynamic type* of the variable.</sub>